# Apply a shadow at both sides of a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I'm currently drawing on the screen. I get smooth lines, I can change the color of my drawings. But I can't find how to apply a shadow to that line.

To draw it, I use :

```
[path strokeWithBlendMode:[path blendMode] alpha:1.0];
```

I saw that I could use `CGContextSetShadowWithColor()` but even though, I'm not sure how to use it since here's what's said in the CGPath reference for `strokeWithBlendMode`:

> This method automatically saves the current graphics state prior to
>   drawing and restores that state when it is done, so you do not have to
>   save the graphics state yourself.

So I don't really know where to put that `CGContextSetShadowWithColor()` or anything else if I can use it.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `CGContextSetShadowwithColor()` then you will need to change the way to draw your bezierpath to the view so that you draw the `CGPath` representation to the `CGContext`. An example is below:

```
UIBezierPath *path;     // this is your path as before
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(context, path.CGPath);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, path.blendMode);
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0), 2.0, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Another way you could do this is to create a new `CAShapeLayer` and draw you path to that by setting it as the path property. This will easily allow you to add a shadow that will only shadow your path.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be trying this !

Comment: It works, but at only one side of the line. And I would like to apply at both sides of it to apply a blurry effect to the whole line.

Comment: Set the shadowOffset to CGSizeZero and adjust the blur value until you find an effect you like.

Comment: using this works. but it becomes way too laggy (iPhone 6s). I'm setting all that in drawRect. Any ideas?